# Custom config in cake.config

Tags: configuration, cakebuild

Cake supports [configuration](https://cakebuild.net/docs/running-builds/configuration/set-configuration-values) in a `cake.config` file.

Can I read *my own* config key/values from that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cake has a [method](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.Configuration/ICakeConfiguration/4007C3B8) to retrieve those values.

Example:

`cake.config`

```ini
[MyCustomConfig]
Foo=Bar
```

`build.cake`

```cs
Information(Context.Configuration.GetValue("MyCustomConfig_Foo"));   // Bar
```

(Note the [underscore](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/7fa4a79e643b258d6d34497d062ac59d3331bd98/src/Cake.Core/Constants.cs#L18-L21) `"_"` - it isn't documented, so I hope it's reliable.)

Comment: You are right, it seems the use of the underscore (`_`) isn't documented. It probably should. Also, note that the configuration you showed above can be overridden by a commandline parameter `--MyCustomConfig_Foo=Baz`

Comment: I created https://github.com/cake-build/website/issues/2483 to track the need to document this.

Comment: lonix, this is now documented at https://cakebuild.net/docs/running-builds/configuration/custom-configurations